# How to go directly to Game Center 'New Game' ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, game-center, ios6.1

I am doing a turn-based game and have a viewController were i set the parameters for the game and would like to jump directly to the Game Center invitation ViewController, se picture.

I have been looking for a solution for this but not been able to find any description of this.

My question is if it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup a GKTurnBasedMatchHelper class which includes a singleton sharedInstance class method you can call Game Center's auto match screen by doing the following:

```
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance]
     findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self];
```

The sharedInstance method in your GCTurnBasedMatchHelper should look like this:

```
+ (GCTurnBasedMatchHelper *) sharedInstance {
    static GCTurnBasedMatchHelper *sharedHelper;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedHelper = [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedHelper;
}
```

You can find a great tutorial on turn based gaming with Game Center in [this article on turn based gaming with Game Center.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1)